# Python appending to binary file works in Unix, not in Windows

Tags: python, windows, unix, file-io

The function below receives file chunks from a web requests and assembles them.  It works perfectly in Unix (OSX) but on Windows, it doesn't.  Specifically, the file does assemble, however it always ends up too small, just a few KB.  I cannot figure out what is causing this.  No exceptions are raised, it all appears to work, except that the final file is not all there.  I've included the entire function for context but I've marked the section which appears not to be working correctly.  (Python 2.7 and Windows Server 2008 R2)

```
@view_config(route_name='upload', renderer='json')
def upload(request):
    r = request.response

    final_dir = 'w:\\foobar'
    filename = request.params.get('flowFilename')
    chunk_number = request.params.get('flowChunkNumber')
    total_chunks = request.params.get('flowTotalChunks')
    try:
        temp_dir = os.path.join(final_dir, request.params.get('flowIdentifier'))
        file_part = os.path.join(temp_dir, '%s.part.%s' % (filename, chunk_number))
        if not os.path.exists(temp_dir):
            os.makedirs(temp_dir)
    except TypeError:
        pass

    if request.method == 'GET':
        if file_part:
            if os.path.isfile(file_part):
                r.status = 200
            else:
                r.status = 404
        return r
    if request.POST:
        try:
            fo = request.params.get('file').file
            f = open(file_part, 'wb')
            f.write(fo.read())
            f.close()
            if chunk_number == total_chunks:
                final_filename = os.path.join(final_dir, filename)
                temp_filename = filename + '_INCOMPLETE'
                #####################################################################
                # This is where is appears to be going wrong...
                final_file = open(temp_filename, 'a+b')
                try:
                    for i in range(1, int(total_chunks) + 1):

                        ff = open(os.path.join(temp_dir, '%s.part.%s' % (filename, i)))
                        final_file.write(ff.read())
                        ff.close()
                    final_file.close()
                    os.rename(temp_filename, final_filename)  # rename to final filename
                    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)  # clean up temp part files
                except:
                    raise
                ####################################################################
            r.status = 200
        except Exception, e:
            print 'ERROR', e.message
            r.status = 404
        return r
```

Comment: Try saving the chunks separately and then join them with some external tool.

Comment: Perhaps in your `ff = open(...)` line you also need to use binary mode?

Comment: If this is Python 2.x, as [the `open` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) explain, `a` mode means that every write goes to the end of the file regardless of seek position on some *nixes, but on others, and on Windows, it doesn't.

Comment: Also, what is your `try:`/`except: raise` supposed to do? That just catches any exception and immediately rethrows it, which should have no effect at all.

Comment: @abarnert: Not clear how that would matter here, since he doesn't seem to do anything but open the file, write to it, and then close it.  There's no seeking going on.

Comment: @BrenBarn I think that's it.  I added 'rb' to the ff file object and it now works perfectly, thanks!